# Recreating classic Snake Game, moveTowards function and OnTriggerEnter2D not working as expect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get recreate the classic snake game, but currently there are two issues happening: the first is that the MoveTowards function doesn't seem to be working.

The second issue is the fact that when the snakeBody is spawned it collides with the snake, even though they aren't near each other.
There are no error messages on the console, the Debug on the ChaseSnake script is showing up, and the collision Debug is too.

i have asked chatGPT for help and he couldn't explain to me what the issue is, just said to try and add a Debug.Log, but the Debug was already there and said to change to FixedUpdate instead, he also offered the option to use transform.translate instead, witch might work but i would like to understand what is going on here.

I was expecting for the snakeBody gameObject to chase the player and if the player collided with the body to be destroyed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SnakeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [SerializeField] private float snakeSpeed = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float Distance = 10;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject snakeBody;

    public Vector3 snakePosition;

    private bool up = false;
    private bool left = false;
    private bool down = false;
    private bool right = true;

    public bool Alive = true;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        snakePosition = transform.position;
    }
    void Move()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * snakeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w") && down != true)
        {
            up = true;
            left = false;
            down = false;
            right = false;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a") && right != true)
        {
            left = true;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            down = false;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("s") && up != true)
        {
            down = true;
            up = false;
            left = false;
            right = false;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 270);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d") && left != true)
        {
            right = true;
            up = false;
            left = false;
            down = false;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("trigger happened but not the if statement");
        if (up == true && collision.gameObject.tag == "Food")
        {
            Distance = Distance + 1;
            Instantiate(snakeBody, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Distance, 0), transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("colidi com a comida");

        }
        if (down == true && collision.gameObject.tag == "Food")
        {
            Distance = Distance + 1;
            Instantiate(snakeBody, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Distance, 0), transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("colidi com a comida");

        }
        if (right == true && collision.gameObject.tag == "Food")
        {
            Distance = Distance + 1;
            Instantiate(snakeBody, new Vector3(transform.position.x - Distance, transform.position.y, 0), transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("colidi com a comida");
        }
        if (left == true && collision.gameObject.tag == "Food")
        {
            Distance = Distance + 1;
            Instantiate(snakeBody, new Vector3(transform.position.x + Distance, transform.position.y, 0), transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("colidi com a comida");
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Body")
        {
            Alive = false;
           // Destroy(gameObject);
            Debug.Log("colidi com meu corpo");
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChaseSnake : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SnakeMovement snakeMovement;
    private float Speed = 4;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        snakeMovement = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<SnakeMovement>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (snakeMovement.Alive == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("I AM CHASING THE SNAKE UHU");

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, snakeMovement.snakePosition, Speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: what is "chasesnake" on?  why does it matter which direction the snake is moving for the food in the trigger, as it would seem you're instantiating the body  not at the end of the snake where ever that maybe, but at a defined position which probably then does clash with the snake, as you need the head to clash with the body but the body to ignore itself (usually)

Comment: the chaseSnake is on the snakeBody, a second gameObject that is spawned when you collide with the food. The directions matter so the snakeBody is always instatiated behind the snake.

Comment: but if you zig zag your snake doesnt sound like it zigzags..  its hard to picture what you see, but the movement should work

Comment: I didn't notice that it wouldn't zig zag, but now that you mention it i guess the snake would walk in a diagonal right? it would take the shortest path, i'll try to write in a different way, but i'm a bit sad that i can't get this simple thing to work

Comment: If you want to avoid diagonal move you can simply check which distance is the smaller one, X or Y axis and move only in that one like e.g. `var distance = snakeMovement.snakePosition - transform.position; if(Mathf.Abs(distance.x) > Mathf.Abs(distance.y)) { /*Move in X axis */ } else { /* Move in Y axis */ }`